# Exit Tour on triggering of any event caused by parent view - Intro.js

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, intro.js

[File Manager - Home Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C5lH.png)
[image: File Manager - Home Normal]
I am using most of my content based on AJAX callbacks. Clicking a link button on my page pops-up a modal (the btn has some class and jquery event is triggered to load that modal-pop-up and shows content). The Tour Guide used in my Application is Intro.js which I downloaded from http://www.introjs.com based on some recommendations from community.

IntroJs is working fine as long as the normal routine is carried out.

Here is my code for that (only related lines are included):

```
elementsArrays = getIntroElements();    //  Get All the elements that can be in tour list

availableElements = getAvailableElements(elementsArrays)    //  Input the Array of Elements and Return Available Elements in page
TotalCount = availableElements.ids.length + availableElements.classes.length + 2;   //  Set the Object for ease-of-access

setUpIntroElements();   //  SetsUp the route path for tourguide to move through

introJs().start();  //  Starts the Tour Guide
```

But when I click a link button (when the tour guide is in progress, that button is accessible at that moment (e.g the target highlighted element is main container and update button is a part of highlighted area. so it is clickable.)), the corresponding modal window pops up but the tour is not done yet. I press left/right arrow keys and the next data-step of introjs appears over my modal popup window. ([Modal popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0jhx.png))
[image: Modal popup window]

Here is my code for trying to shut the tour down

```
//  Close the wizard on any button click or disabled clicking any button there in the page
$("body").on("click", ".filemgt-file-index a", function(e){
    if( $(".introjs-showElement")[0] )  //  case: the tour is in process
    {
        //e.stopPropagation();  //  not working
        e.stopImmediatePropagation()    //  not working

        //var esc = $.event("keydown", {keyCode:27});
        //$("body").trigger(esc);   //  didnt work at all

        //  Trigger the below event
        //  a.introjs-button.introjs-skipbutton
        introJs().exit();   //  Exit the Tour and Work on new set   //  doesn't work very well
        //  need to apply "press Esc event" programmatically in jquery
        //  Triggering event equavalent to pressing Esc button
        //  disable all events associated with it 
        introJs().exitIntro()
    }
});
```

When I close/cancel my modal window, still the tour is not terminated and pressing left/right arrow key shows the corresponding data-step element intro. ([File Manager - Home (after Closing Modal popup)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KE8g.png))
[image: File Manager - Home (after Closing Modal popup)]

What I want to achieve is, if any of the links within tour guide is clicked, the tour should end and the new modal should popup with all focus on it.

The attached images illustrate what the situation is and what exactly I want to have. take a look and them, and let me know if I am missing something in the problem statement.

Thank you very much in Advance.
Stay Blessed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a standard solution but it helped me fix my problem on the go.

while looking at the source code appeared in my browser window (inspect Element (F12 Function-key), I found a class "introjs-skipbutton" against skip button of tool-tip pop.

I found that clicking on this button exits the tour so I put the below code in my JQUERY file:

```
//  Close the wizard on any button click or disabled clicking any button there in the page
$("body").on("click", ".main_container_div_of_view a", function(e){
    if( $(".introjs-showElement")[0] )  //  case: the tour is in process
    {
        $('.introjs-skipbutton').click();   //  Terminate Introduction
    }
});
```

This does the trick and exits the tour. But still its not a standard practice in my opinion.

Comment: This is the basis for a good solution. Having a click handler on a high ancestor, you'll have every click run through your handler. In your case, it's through every anchor link which may satisfy your needs. I chose to bind the handler to the window's "click" event. Then the handler checks the event target hasClass('introjs-overlay') and closest('.introjs-tooltip') exists. If neither condition, then it's a non-introjs click, so I stop the tour. Thx Code Builder.

Comment: This is the basis for what I did (angular, and my own webTourService): `let ael = angular.element(element);
if (!ael.hasClass('introjs-overlay')) {
    let elTooltip = element.closest('.introjs-tooltip');
    if (!elTooltip) {
        webTourService.stopTour();
    }
}`